# Multiple tableview within one view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewcontroller

I was wandering if its possible to have more than one uiTableView in one ViewController.

For example:

tableView1 and tableView2 in one view controller.

Initial start up of view controller, tableView2 should be disabled and not visible.

tableView1 should show the data associated with it.

When user selects a row from tableView1... it should then show the data corresponding to the selected row in tableView2.

tableView1 should still be enabled, and if user selects another row, the contents of tableView2 should also change respectively.

Thanks for any help or guidance given. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can do this. This is 5 minutes in storyboard.

You should choose `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`!) 
And create something like this:

[image]

Then you should create object references with a `ctrl` key.

[image]

You have to remember that you have to set delegate and dataSource in both tableViews to your ViewController:

[image]

And in yout second table view set initialView to hidden.

Then in your code in method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you should in first line call:

`[self.mySecondTableView setHidden:NO]`

and do all your stuff later. That's it.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Now i realize that you have set topic to "multiple" tableViews. This solution is messy enough for two TableViews. I suggest you to use container, and then all tableView will have own ViewController.

Comment: I think this solution is not too messy. Just to be careful which tableView is calling in the dataSource and delegate implementation. Checking by comparing the tableViews calling the delegate/dataSource with the outlets.

Comment: Right, i should use word "messy enought" ;)

Comment: Thanks i think i will only have two table views within one view controller. I am going to try the above now

Answer (score 0):

You can set different tags and outlets for this two TableView.

Then in

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad

self.yourSecondTableView.hidden = YES;
```

to hide second tableView

and when delegates methods was called

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

or

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can ask for tag like

```
if (tableView.tag == yourSecondTableViewTag) 
    return something
```

Comment: You dont have use tag for this kind of operation. Delegate methods always have "sender" object in method parameter. So you can simply use:
`if(tableView == self.firstTableView) { // do something in tableView1 } else if(tableView == self.secondTableView) ...`